# TikZ macro with list of integers as argument

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to write a macro that takes lists as some of its arguments and wonder how to best access the individual entries of these lists.

For example, I would like something of the sort

```
\newcommand\mycommand[4]{
\pgfmathsetmacro \n {{#1}}
\pgfmathsetmacro \k {{#2}}

\foreach \i in {\k,...,\n} {
 \draw (#3[\i],0) -- (#4[\i]) {};
}
}
```

which would take arguments such as

```
\mycommand{10}{3}{1,2,5}{6,9,10}
```

I would need to access both lists individually, so that working with a list of pairs seems not be an option. Basically my question is how to make the part #3[\i] work, which should return item number i in the list that is the third argument of the function.

Comment: The `\getargsC{}` macro of the `readarray` package (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2132/how-to-define-a-command-that-takes-more-than-9-arguments/99271#99271) allows a list of space-separated arguments that get placed into `\argi`, `\argii`, `\argiii`, etc. in roman numeral format.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, Steven! Is there also a way to access, say, number 25 by something like \arg[27] instead of the roman numbering?

Comment: `\csname arg\romannumeral 27\endcsname`, which you can implement as `\def\myarg#1{\csname arg\romannumeral#1\endcsname}` and invoke as `\myarg{27}`.

Comment: ah, nice! one more question: when I want to use that in a \foreach \i in ... loop, \myarg{\i} seems not to work? What would be the right way of accessing entry number \i?

Comment: I am not a `\foreach` expert, and you have not provided a complete length of code to compile.  That said, I can do things like `\foreach \y in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr\myarg{2}-1}` successfully, followed by a `\draw` that uses `\y`.

Comment: I am trying to do     \foreach \i in {1,...,10} { \node at (\i,0) {\myarg{\i}}; } which however fails for me

Answer (score 1):

This is a follow up to comments between the OP and myself.

Since full code was not provided and since I don't really know `tikz` at all, I grabbed another answer of mine at [\foreach problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161850/foreach-problem/161851#161851) and show how to insert arguments from `readarray` package's `\getargC` macro into both `\draw` and `\node` macros, using the loop index as the argument.

Given an earlier call to `\getargsC{15 43 35 21 1}`, the particular stretch of code where that is used is

```
\foreach \y in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr\CylGrad-1}
    {\draw[semithick] (0,\y/\CylGrad)
        arc (270:260:1 and \CylRatio) ;
    \draw[semithick] (0,\y/\CylGrad)
        arc (270:280:1 and \CylRatio) (0.2,\y/\CylGrad)
        node[right,yslant=\CylRatio](\y){\footnotesize \myarg{\y}};% <--\myarg used here
    \node at (0,\y/\CylGrad){\myarg{\numexpr\y+1}};}; % <--\myarg used here
\fi
```

Here is the full MWE.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{readarray}
\def\myarg#1{\csname arg\romannumeral#1\endcsname}

\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd,
  CylCol/.store in=\CylCol,
  CylCol=gray,
  CylFillCol/.store in=\CylFillCol,
  CylFillCol=blue,
  CylFill/.store in=\CylFill,
  CylFill=0,
  CylRatio/.store in=\CylRatio,
  CylRatio=.08,  
  CylGrad/.store in=\CylGrad,
  CylGrad=5,
  CylSecondGrad/.store in=\CylSecondGrad,
  CylSecondGrad=0,
   }

\newcommand{\TikzCylindre}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}[#1]
    % Grisé des surfaces du cylindre.
    \shade[left color=\CylCol!30, right color=\CylCol!5]%
         (-1,1)--(-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and \CylRatio) --(1,0) -- (1,1);
    \shade[left color=\CylCol!5, right color=\CylCol!30]%
        (0,1) ellipse (1 and \CylRatio);
    \draw[\CylCol!50] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and \CylRatio)--(-1,0) ;

    % Remplissage du cylindre
    \shade[left color=\CylFillCol!40, right color=\CylFillCol!10]%
         (-1,\CylFill)--(-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and \CylRatio) --(1,0) -- (1,\CylFill);
    \fill[color=\CylFillCol!25] (0,\CylFill) ellipse (1 and \CylRatio);
    \draw[\CylFillCol!50!black!50] (1,0) arc (0:180:1 and \CylRatio)--(-1,0) ;
    \draw[\CylFillCol!50!black!50] (0,\CylFill) ellipse (1 and \CylRatio) ;

    % dessin des bords du cylindre
    \draw[semithick] (-1,1)--(-1,0) arc (180:360:1 and \CylRatio)--(1,0)--(1,1);
    \draw[semithick] (0,1) ellipse (1 and \CylRatio);   

        \begin{scope}[shift={(0,-\CylRatio)}]
        \ifnum\CylGrad>0
        \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr\CylGrad-1}
            {\draw[semithick] (0,\y/\CylGrad)
                arc (270:260:1 and \CylRatio) ;
            \draw[semithick] (0,\y/\CylGrad)
                arc (270:280:1 and \CylRatio) (0.2,\y/\CylGrad)
                node[right,yslant=\CylRatio](\y){\footnotesize \myarg{\y}};% <--\myarg used here
            \node at (0,\y/\CylGrad){\myarg{\numexpr\y+1}};}; % <--\myarg used here
        \fi

        \ifnum\CylSecondGrad>0
        \foreach \y in {1,2,...,\the\numexpr\CylSecondGrad}
        {\draw(0,\y/\CylSecondGrad) arc (270:265:1 and \CylRatio) ;
        \draw (0,\y/\CylSecondGrad) arc (270:275:1 and \CylRatio) ;
        };
        \fi
        \end{scope} ;

    \end{scope}
    }

\begin{document}

\getargsC{15 43 35 21 1}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \TikzCylindre[x=1.5cm,y=4cm,CylFill=.8,CylSecondGrad=10] ;

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]