# Why doesn't this \foreach work?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, loops, for-loop

I don't understand why this doesn't work. I changed `x` to `y` and `z` but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
    ]
    \addplot[red, domain=0:6, samples=10,]{x};
    \foreach \x in {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.}
        \node[] at (\x , 1)  {Hello};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

**Added:** but it works properly for `\addplot` provided the variable name is neither `\x`nor `\y`

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    ]
    \foreach \w in {1,2,...,5} {
    \addplot[red, domain=0:6, samples=10,]{\w * x};
    \addplot[blue, mark=square, ycomb] coordinates {(\w, \w^2 - 1)};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach`:

```
\pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,5} {
    \node[]  at (#1 , 1)  {Hello};
}
```

where the parameter is availalbe as `#1`. This yields:

[image]

#### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
    legend style={
    legend pos= north west,},
    legend style={%at={(0.5,0.95)},anchor=north,
    legend columns=1},
    ]
    \addplot[red, domain=0:6, samples=10,]{x};
    
    \pgfplotsinvokeforeach{1,2,3,4,5} {
        \node[]  at (#1 , 1)  {Hello};
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Cuold you please check my comment (with the ink) on the other answer ?

Comment: @Physor: That would make a very good separate question. I suspect it has to do with how nodes are created at the end of the `axis` environemnt, where as in the other question regarding a [\foreach problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161850/4301) does not do the drawing in an `axis` environment.

Comment: As far as i unterstand your question, this osbecause `\foreach` works without  special ptroblems on tikz pictures  but not inside pgfplots' axis environment , where `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` must  ne used.

Comment: i added something, maybe interesting!

Comment: @Physor: I still recommend that you post anohter question. Note that what you posted does not a drawing but calls an internal `pgfplots` function do do a graph.

Answer (score 4):

`\x` needs to be expanded, because it is in its own `\foreach` group and its value is thus effervescent.  By expanding it first, the actual value of `\x` is passed to `\node`, rather than an indirect reference to `\x`, which does not persist.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}
%\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    grid=major,
    xmin = 0, xmax = 6,
    legend style={
    legend pos= north west,},
    legend style={%at={(0.5,0.95)},anchor=north,
    legend columns=1},
    ]
    \addplot[red, domain=0:6, samples=10,]{x};
    \foreach \x in {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.}
        \def\tmp{\node[] at (}
        \expandafter\tmp\x , 1)  {Hello};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What a maneuver! (```\def\tmp{\node[] at (}```), isn't there another way to use loops for nodes ?

Comment: @Physor I can think of several other ways, but each one is even uglier, LOL.  The bottom line is the loop variable `\x` needs to be expanded as the argument to `\node`.

Comment: @Physor or `  \foreach \x in {1.,2.,3.,4.,5.}
       { \edef\tmp{\noexpand \node[] at (\x , 1)  {Hello}}\tmp;}`

Comment: Thanks a lot but why doesn't this OP seem to need that https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161850/foreach-problem